# Rails 4 not respecting the default_scope when using a has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, default-scope

I have a model class that has a default scope, something like this

```
class Avatar
  self.table_name = 'attachments'
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { where(type: 'avatar') }
end

class User
  has_one :avatar
end
```

I expected `User.first.avatar` to return the first attachment that User created where the type is avatar. Instead I am getting the User's first attachment (regardless of type).

I have to specify the type manually to get it to work:

```
has_one :avatar, -> { where(type: 'avatar') }
```

Why do associations not respect default_scope? I should add that `Avatar.all` returns the expected results (only where type is 'avatar').

Comment: Also, `User.first.avatars` does not respect default_scope if I change it to a has_many relationship.

Comment: Are you sure? I use that a lot: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/app/models/event.rb#L23 It might be some gem causing this.